# Spin and rotation of gluon field components

Tags: special-relativity, particle-physics, quantum-chromodynamics, gluons

The [gluon field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gluon_field) has 4 spacetime components: $A_\mu = (A_0, A_1, A_2, A_3)$, like the electromagnetic field.
Firstly, how to find each component of the gluon field?
And how to perform a rotation on those components, in order to prove that the gluon field has really spin 1?

Comment: Is this useful? https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/302832/226902, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/555696/226902.

Comment: Thank you for the replay, but I'm looking for the derivation of the components, not their relation to the SU(3) group.

Comment: What do you mean by "derivation of the components"? Each component depends on the reference system used and on the specific configuration of the field (at least in its classical limit). It's like asking "how to find each component of the electromagnetic field", or "each component of the velocity field of water in a turbulent river"... there is no general formula, you have to solve the specific dynamical set of equations for a given initial condition.